# Configuring the application in one place

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I have an application in React Native that I build and publish through **AppCenter**

- Android
- iOS

At the moment **package** and **Bundle Id** have been defined separately for Android and iOS

The situation is similar with application versioning for both systems. I have to do it separately

Is there any way to configure in one file?

I know there is an `app.json` file but in every project I see it looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "nameapp",
  "displayName": "NameApp"
}
```

Only when someone uses Expo is additional information

I want to point out here that I don't use Expo

Answer (score 0):

use the react-native-rename npm package.

Install using

```
npm install react-native-rename -g
```

Then from the root of your React Native project execute the following

```
react-native-rename "MyApp" -b com.mycompany.myapp
```